# how to handle xml data in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am newbie in javascript **xml** data handling. Currently, my ajax call to a server, and the server returns **xml** data, I don't know how to parse the xml data to get some values.

My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/someinterface/the-id',
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'application/xml',
            data: {id: 43},
            success: function(data) {

                //handle the data

            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                alert('error happens');
            }
         })
```

the returned **xml** data looks like:

```
<DOCUMENT>
  <AGE>16</AGE>
  <USERNAME>default user</USERNAME>
  <SECURITYID>1111</SECURITYID>
...
```

how to parse the xml data to get for example "USERNAME" in my javascript ??

------------EDIT------------

I tried to use your proposed ways, but now I got error message:

**XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{120e8c1d-5174-4e94-9ebb-2bffda80b170} Line Number 1, Column 1:
^**

and the ajax call result to the **error function**

-------------------**PARTLY SOLVED**------------------------

Finally, I found the reason is that my application is running on jetty server on localhost:**8080**, while my ajax is requesting xml data on tomcat server which is running on localhost:**8085**. Because of the domain port are different, I got the weired problem. Now, after I move my application to tomcat server and request tomcat server, I got the xml response successfully.

The ajax call goes to the success function, and I use

```
success: function(data){
           xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
            $xml = $(xmlDoc);
            $userName = $xml.find('USERNAME');  
            var userName = $userName.text();
            alert('1');
            alert(userName);
}
```

I got alert('1') in my browser, **BUT** I do not get alert(userName) , I don't know why... So I put here "PARTLY SOLVED", so...why I do not get my userName alert..

Comment: @Mallon: which one did you use. What is the jquery version u r using?

Comment: Hi, I have tried all the suggested ways, also tried directly alert out the data like "alert(data)" in success function, but when run it in browser, it calls the error function and pop up the alert in error function.

Comment: @Mallon: are u sure your server is not returning empty xml?

Comment: Hi, Amitabh, I am sure my server returned an xml, because I copied and pasted the URL with parameter to the browser, and the browser showd the xml data correctly. The only exception is in Firefox, the browswer popup an message "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it." But it still show the xml data in a xml format like what I showed in the above post.

Comment: try  dataType : 'xml' instead of 'application/xml'

Comment: I tried both 'application/xml' and 'xml', also tried omit it. But problem is still there in either way:(

Comment: is the url on the same server and port as your application? Otherwise you will run into cross domain problems with ajax.

Comment: and also be sure to check the xhr call with Firebug to see that the request goes out as expected, and returns as expected

Comment: Hi, Nikalas, I am thinking about the same thing. wait a second.

Comment: Hi, yes, it is because of different port number, check my updates in the above post under text "PARTLY SOLVED"

Comment: Great, have you inspected the $userName object in Firebug?

Comment: I only see the "response" in firebug Net/XHR is the whole xml data, I did not found userName. In server console there is an warning message " WARN ["http-apr-8085"-exec-3] (HttpMethodBase.java:682) - Going to buffer response body of large or unknown size. Using getResponseBodyAsStream instead is recommended."

Comment: I have edited my answer. please try that.

Comment: Hi, Amitabh, I am not besides my work machine now, I will try your answer tomorrow, and let you know. thank you.

Comment: Hi, Amitabh, I tried your updated answer, it works now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jquery xml parsing.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

So in your Success function.

```
success: function(data) {
    //xmlDoc = $.parseXML( data);
    $xml = $( data);
    $userName = $xml.find('USERNAME');  
    var uName = $userName.text();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The browser will basically handle it for you:

```
success: function(data) {
  var username = $(data).find('username').text();
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing the `dataType` parameter. It's not expected to be a MIME type. Instead, it should one of these: "xml", "html", "script", "json", "jsonp" or "text". In your case, "xml" (or omit it completely and jQuery will guess it for you):

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (scroll down to "dataTypeString").

**Update:**

So far, it looks that your problem is that your server side script is crashing and you don't even have valid XML. Whatever, I've put together a small example in case it helps:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/test.xml",
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    dataType: "xml",
    data: {id: 43},
    success: function(data) {
        var output = "Usernames:\n";
        $(data).find("USERNAME").each(function(){
            output += "\n- " + $(this).text();
        });
        alert(output);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
        alert("error happens");
    }
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont get your point, what do you mean about "misusing" the datatype. I checked your link, I found the text "In particular, XML must be declared by the server as text/xml or application/xml for consistent results." If you check my post, I do use dataType: 'application/xml'. But thank you anyhow :)

Comment: Hi, I tried omit it, the browser do guessed it for me, but this does not solve my problem, the problem is still there . Thank you.

Comment: @Mellon: Please read my answer carefully. I said you can **not** use `dataType: "application/xml"` and you reply that you **are** using it.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your answer. I will try it tomorrow and let you know. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Use Json data type instead, it's designed to be used with javascript.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
url: url,
dataType: 'json',
data: data,
success: callback
});
```

Comment: Since this project required xml data response, so I can not use json now.

Comment: OK, sorry. Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following snippet in your function to put the XML result string in a wrapped jQuery set.

```
var xmlString = data;

//IE XML parser needs to use an ActiveXObject
if ($.browser.msie) {
    unwrappedXml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    unwrappedXml.async = false;
    unwrappedXml.loadXML(xmlString);
    }
else {
    unwrappedXml = xmlString;
}

var xml = $(unwrappedXml);
xml.find(selector);
```